# VBA SSRS trying to look for specific characters in a string then return something else

Tags: vba, reporting-services

I am trying to pick out some characters within a string and then capture a certain part of it then converting it into something else.

For example if "Picked 1 with 100% return" I want the output to be "100". So far all attempts have been in vain.

so far the VBA I have is noted below in the report properties of my template. (Yes I have changed the expression in the field that I need it to reflect in).

```
Public Function ChangePercentage(ByVal s As String) As String
s= s.Trim()
If s.ToUpper Like "100%*".ToUpper = True Then
Return "100"
Else : Return S
End If
End Function
```

Any help would be much appricicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it indeed is VBA that you're working with, you'll need to correct it to make it look this :

```
Public Function ChangePercentage(ByVal str As String) As String
    str = Trim(str)
    If UCase(str) Like "*100%*" Then
        ChangePercentage = "100"
    Else
        ChangePercentage = str
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can simplify it further: you don't actually need `Trim` and `Ucase`

Comment: Is what I expected, but I didn't take the liberty to remove them, figured it would be good to learn some VBA basics at the same time :)

Comment: @BernardSaucier, thanks for that. I have managed to get the results that I needed. I know VBA, but when it comes down to trim etc, I don't want to take any chances as where the thing was configured I don't know if there was any extra spaces that were put in. Always better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Let me explain why he made a good point by saying it wasn't needed. By using `Like` and `*` on both sides, you're looking for ANYTHING that has "100%" in it. Therefore, uppercase or not, trailing spaces or not, you'll always return true if "100%" is somewhere inside the string.